# Silverlight Toolkit - DragDrop StackedColumnSeries Chart

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, charts, toolkit

I have a Stacked Column Chart from the Silverlight Toolkit from April 2011.

I wish to select and drag one layer from a stack into a regular column chart for details.

Is this possible? I can handle all logic in code but I need the sweet semi transperant adorner...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a fun challenge! Silverlight does not have an adorner layer. The best way to achieve this sort of effect is to use a `Popup`. These live outside of the visual tree, allowing you to use them to place content over your current visuals. You can create a full-screen `Popup`, then grab a copy of the series you want to drag (perhaps using a `WriteableBitmap`).

See for example this blog post which animates an element by copying it into a `Popup`:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/04/metro-in-motion-3-flying-titles/